# .extern vs. .data in MIPS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

When programming MIPS assembly (specifically in a classroom context using MARS), when would one use the `.extern` directive as opposed to simply putting a label in the `.data` section?

Answer (score 1):

In MARS you can compile multiple files.
If you want to access a label (global variable) from another file you need to place it in a global data segment (using the .extern).

For example:

**File1.asm**

```
.data
.extern local 4
.text
    li $t0, 0x00000041
    la $t1, local
    sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

**File2.asm**

```
.data
.text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, local
    syscall
```

With .extern you can read *local* from **File2.asm**

For more information read:
http://danzig.jct.ac.il/mips/architecture.html